# A map and set which uses contiguous memory and has a reserve function

Tags: c++, boost, collections, stl

I use several maps and sets. The lack of contiguous memory, and high number of (de)allocations, is a performance bottleneck. I need a mainly STL-compatbile map and set class which can use a contiguous block of memory for internal objects (or multiple blocks).  It also needs to have a `reserve` function so that I can preallocate for expected sizes.

Before I write my own I'd like to check what is available first. Is there something in Boost which does this? Does somebody know of an available implementation elsewhere?

---

Intrusive collection types are not usable here as the same objects need to exist in several collections. As far as I know STL memory pools are per-type, not per instance (kind of, sort of not, many caveats).  These global pools are not efficient with respect to memory locality in mutli-cpu/core processing.

Object pools don't work as the types will be shared between instance but their pool should not.

In many cases a hash map may be an option.

Comment: Can you use the STL `map` and `set` containers with a suitable custom node allocator?  (For example, the Visual C++ Standard Library ships with [a set of custom allocators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292134.aspx) with different performance characteristics (I'm sure there are other allocators available that are more portable; those are just the first ones that come to mind).)

Comment: @James, that's what I meant with object pools. STL doesn't support per-instance allocators, only per-type allocators.

Comment: Object pool is the rightest way to handle memory related performance problems. I'd change other conditions to make object pools could be used. By the way, you can store real objects in vector or deque and use map/set only for reference/pointer.

Comment: Normal STL map/set is usually backed by balanced tree structure. So if one make contiguous memory map/set, many chances are there it will be memory inefficient implementation. On the other hand, if you can determine overall data size or key diversity, you could employ hash map/set. Hash based containers are more likely be contiguous memory.

Comment: @Dan, memory pools must be per instance in order to take advantage of per-core memory locality. By sharing one pool I'll be sharing too many memory segments across the cores. I already am using pointers. I'll consider hash maps as a possibility.

Comment: @edA: huh? That's unlikely to make a measurable difference. Sounds like premature optimization.

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at this: [Google Sparse Hash Map](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash). It's been my favorite C++ library since I stumbled upon it some years ago.

Its performance is incredible, has both a map and a set class, and has the asked-for reserve functions. I've switched over countless projects from various other map-like datastructures to google sparsehash with incredible results. The syntax is drop-in compatible with the C++0x `unordered_map` (terrible, terrible name!), but has extra functions and features as well.

Internally, it is implemented with a hash table using the sparsehashing technique.

EDIT (May 13, 2015)

As this has become a popular answer, I just wanted to point out two other map-like structures I have been using in recent years. The [**M**iscellaneous **C**ontainer **T**emplates (MCT) library](https://launchpad.net/libmct) provides drop-in compatible high-performance unorderd_map implementations in a few varieties:

> It provides six general-purpose hash table containers —
>   closed_hash_set, closed_hash_map, linked_hash_set, linked_hash_map,
>   forward_hash_set and forward_hash_map. The first two are very similar
>   to TR1 unordered_set and unordered_map. The linked ones provide
>   additional functionality, while forward hash tables are more efficient
>   than linked, but have restricted interface. In some cases performance
>   of the closed_hash_* containers can be improved even further with
>   optional intrusiveness support.

And [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) by facebook has some really great structures. They don't have a drop-in unordered_map replacement per-se, but there's a lock-free/thread-safe implementation of unordered_map and building things around `fbvector` can result in huge performance gains due to better memory usage and layout.

In my testing, for single-threaded code Google's `dense_hash_map` is still my preferred option for maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.  `unordered_map` is actually an okay name -- it follows the convention of naming the abstract collection rather than the backing structure.

Comment: Well, it's not a 100% drop-in replacement, you need a ``set_empty_key()`` call at least.

Comment: I think if you take the google dense_map, it cannot be drop-in because of iterator invalidation upon rehash. this is exactly because of this very reason that C++ std implementations of `unordered` cannot perform as well. It is in the standard spec that iterators do not invalidate on insert/erase of unrelated keys. Which mean std-based stuff is forced to use closed-address hashin in practice. google stuff is open address, and do not respect the standard. therefore not drop in.

Answer (score 7):

Boost.Interprocess and Boost.Container provide flat set and flat map that could help you to improve the performances of your application.

See https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/move/libs/container/doc/html/boost_container_reference.html#header.boost.container.flat_set_hpp

Comment: Yes! That looks like what I want. I'll check the performance characteristics of it.

Comment: Sorry, I have to uncheck the "answer" item here. While this set/map are useful, they will likely have bad insertion performance (as they work like a sorted vector).

Answer (score 6):

A recent [post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/212083) on the Boost mailing list discussed something similar to this.

Howard Hinnant has created an allocator which can use the stack instead of the heap.

http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html

Comment: Thanks. While perhaps not a general solution I think I can use this in a few places. This however makes use of the quasi-functional per-instance allocators in the STL (I think 0x cleans this up to work better)

Comment: @edA: you're right, it's guaranteed to work with C++0x but not with C++03 even though I seem to recall it does work with gcc / VC.

Answer (score 6):

You could just use a vector and binary search it for contiguous storage and reserve() as well as maintaining O(logn). Inserting would be more expensive, though.

Comment: For the set case this would probably work in some situations, especially those which do all the inserts before any lookups.  Too bad std::binary_search doesn't return an iterator, that would have been convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Google's [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html). It is a drop-in replacement for malloc, which might speed up your program. TCMalloc is specifically designed for multiple threads.

Comment: I have yet to check if tcmalloc will perform better than glibc's ptmalloc. In general my goal is to avoid the allocations completely as they shouldn't be needed.